# show last modified (date) code works but with wrong output

Tags: c#, .net

So i have this

```
 Console.WriteLine("Last Updated: " + System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(@"D:\somepath")
```

This does work, but with the wrong output, what im getting is

1/1/1601 for some reason..

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `GetLastWriteTimeUtc` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

The problem is that the file does not exist.

You might wonder why this happens. The reason is that the underlying system call returns a 64-bit integer that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that had elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1601 UTC at the time the file was last modified ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime(v=vs.110).aspx)). As a special case, if the file does not exist, then the underlying system call returns `0`.

It would be nice if .NET did something to handle this special case, but it does not. So if the file does not exist then `GetLastWriteTimeUtc` returns the earliest possible date.

Answer (score 0):

The files does not exist. You will see that with existing file it will respond properly.